# PRI request method and host undefined

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, npm, pm2

i am running node.js app and lightsail instance and using nginx to redirect api calls to my node server. I have implemented logger who sends me mail whenever some error occured . So i have been getting email about PRI method and host undefined . below i attached screenshot , can anybody help to know the reason or to stop it.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m87WR.png)

Comment: It might be application level issue, node.js or its module, not looking like `nginx` causing problem here